# Easiest way to create a dynamic heatmap of the United States

Tags: google-maps, mapping, heatmap

thanks for all the help the last few days. I'm hoping someone knows this one.

I'm looking to dynamically create a heatmap of data based on user input, then color certain states based on the response. Like a poll for voting, for example. I'd like to do something like this...
http://www.trulia.com/home_prices/

What is going to be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I would call this a thematic map not a heatmap http://blog.spatialkey.com/2010/02/comparing-thematic-maps-with-density-heatmaps/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) also offers maps.

Here's a (completely made up) example: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this indeed looks like the simplest way to do this.

Comment: That is AWESOME! +10 if I could. I've wanted to do something similar on a website of mine, and was thinking, okay, now I have to find some good bitmaps of the states, overlay them in PNG format, maintain all the logic, etc etc. I didn't realize Google has an API you can just construct URLs from.

Answer (score 4):

Another very easy solution is [OpenHeatMap.com](http://www.openheatmap.com). They support pegging data to a variety of map shapes, including US states.

Comment: Yes this one was perfect - I had a map in seconds with zero code.

Comment: No longer available

Answer (score 1):

[OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) is a javascript library for displaying tiled maps and related elements (polygon, line, etc) on top of these tiles.

It supports a number of back-ends for map data, including google's data.

Samples are available [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples)